# What is meant by "side of a curve"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, mapping-class-group

I'm currently reading "A primer on mapping class groups" by Farb-Magalit. A notion that often turns up is that of a "side of a curve". For example in the proof of Proposition 3.2 or in the proof that the center of the mapping class group of $S_g$ is trivial, whenever $g \geq 3$.

I just can't seem to find any definition for "side" of a curve online. Also, what is meant by "two edges"? I can imagine what edges should be, when we build a simplex of 2 points and 2 edges, but with one point and one edge?

[[image: Proof that <span class=]$Z(MCG(S_g)) \cong 1$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HVTr.png)

Comment: the key concept is that of **regular neigbourhood**

Comment: Where is the mention of the concept of "side" of a curve in the images in this question?

Comment: @MichaelHardy, last sentence, page 79

Comment: @janmarqz : Strange browser behavior: When I try to find occurrences of "side", I not only find the instances in what you typed highlighted in yellow, but part of the word "Consider" highlighted in yellow. But the one you mention in that last sentence is not highlighted.

Comment: I didn't highlighted there. And the *control f* doesn't detect word occurrences on pictures

Answer (score 1):

It is related with the regular neighborhood of the curve: a simple closed curve in an orientable surface has as a regular neighborhood an annular subsurface, while in a non orientable surface a regular neighborhood it will be a Möbius band.

The boundary of a regular neighbourhood of an annular subsurface has two components while a Möbius strip has one.